# Clicking submit button using javascript and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I guess I have never tried to do this before ... I have a button on a page.

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Submit">
```

And a javascript function that includes:

```
function clickit()
{
alert(document.getElementById('btn').value);
document.getElementById('btn').click();
}
```

Using Firefox, the button is not clicked - i.e. the form is not submitted. The alert shows, but the form does not get submitted. Why won't Firefox click a button?

Comment: You can submit a form directly with `document.getElementById("myform").submit();`

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. This is a asp.net page. I need the button to be 'clicked' - because it is the trigger for an update panel. Works fine in IE and Chrome. Why won't Firefox do something as simple as clicking a submit button in code?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `document.getElementById('btn').form.submit()`. Browsers are supposed to simulate a *click* event if an element implementing the *EventTarget* interface has its *click* method called (see [*W3C DOM Level 3 Events §3.5*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-activation). There was a time when Firefox didn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `div` or anything besides a `INPUT` element if you want to bind the click event to it. If `<INPUT>` is inside a form body, you might run into weird issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to submit a form with a button I would recommend that you just use a `<div>` element with a click handler rather than an input. It will give you a little more flexibility. If you do that then you should be able to just select your form and use the [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) API to submit the form.

If you really can't modify the code enough to do this and are having trouble selecting and submitting here is how you will need to do that using both jQuery and DOM.

**The jQuery Way:**

```
$("my selector").trigger("click")
```

You may run into issues around focus if you're running in PhantomJS or you've got a window like a test runner that is not in focus. In this case you can use:

```
$(<my selector>).triggerHandler(<my event>)
```

**The DOM API way**

This will just trigger the event (the equivalent of the first example)

```
// Create the event
var event = new CustomEvent("name-of-event", { "detail": "Example of an event" });

// Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can also simulate a click with the actual DOM method

```
var button = document.getElementById('my-button');
button.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why won't Firefox click a button?

I seem to recall that early versions of Firefox didn't allow calling of listeners that way for security reasons. However, I think those reasons have been addressed in other ways and now you should be able to call the *click* handler directly. The following submits the form in Firefox 34:

```
<form onsubmit="alert('submitted!!')">
  <input name="foo" value="foo">
  <input type="submit" id="aa">
</form>
<br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('aa').click();">Click the submit button</button>
```

The form's submit listener is called and the form is submitted, so calling the submit button's *click* method is doing what it's supposed to.

This method doesn't work for all listeners though, *click* is a special case, see [W3C DOM Level 3 Events Specification, *§3.5 Activation triggers and behavior*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-activation).